# Access the Shapoint Online Search API using authenticated client context or web request in WPF

Tags: sharepoint-online

I want to access Search API from SharePoint Online site. I am using XBAP to access the SharePoint Online Search API, but I am getting "The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden" error. I tried to use Claims based authentication, but not able to get authenticated cookies (getting Null cookie) in WPF application.
I want WPF , because I can access the javascript code from sharepoint page and update to sharepoint page depending upon search results from search response.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the SharePoint 2013 Managed Client Object Model?

There is a class called [SharePointOnlineCredentials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.sharepointonlinecredentials.aspx) that will let you specify a username and password. [This blog post](http://www.vrdmn.com/2013/01/authenticating-net-client-object-model.html) has an example of using the class.